# Bins in Stata that will work in cem

Tags: match, stata

In Stata is it possible (using the `cem` command) to create overlapping bins? For example, if a record in my treatment has `DATE` January 1, 2012, I want a match to be 'true' if a control record's `DATE` is within 2 days in either direction. I tried coding the bins manually with the treatment dates in the middle but since I have thousands of dates this is taking too long.

Using the above example control cases that would match could have dates December 30, 2011; December 31, 2011; January 1, 2012; January 2, 2012; or January 3, 2012.

Comment: Presumably an allusion to http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0176 Such references to user-written software are helpful to many. Please regard them as not only desired, but required.

Comment: It seems you managed to code what you want but you need to automatize the process. Why not add a minimal example of what you have done, including output?

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> I want a match to be 'true' if a control record's DATE is within 2 days 
>   in either direction.

I have not checked the inner workings of the user-written command `cem`, but the variable `cem_matched` 
(created after running `cem`) denotes whether an observation is matched or not and it 
seems to depend on the observation belonging to a stratum in which there are 
*control* and *treatment* observations. If a stratum has controled **and** treated
observations, they are all considered matched and `cem_matched = 1`. If not, 
then all observations in the stratum have `cem_matched = 0`. So I do not see very 
well how you want to modify this variable using as reference another.

Maybe you want to create the strata using the `DATE` variable. I'm no expert, 
but to my knowledge, an observation must belong exclusively to one stratum or
another (this seems true for `cem`, at least). Overlapping bins violates this. 
Your rule implies observations that could be to the right and left of a 
certain cutpoint. From `help cem`:

> . cem age (10 20 30 40 50) education (scott) re74, treatment(treated)
>
> will coarsen the first variable, age into bins of (0-10), (10-20), (20-30), (30-40), (40-50) and (50+).

As you see, non-overlapping bins. What would it do if some overlapped? Where 
would it assign the observation, to the bin on the left or to the right? 
Some other criteria would be needed.

Maybe you want to discard (or flag) some observations per stratum based on the 
`DATE` variable, **after** you run `cem` with other confounding covariates?
I'm not sure. Recall however that `date` variables in Stata can be computed on. See for example: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/modules/dates.htm

Note: `cem` is made available running `ssc install cem`.